# debian unstable and apt upgrade policies with installed experimental packages

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running debian/unstable, in order to build some package I had to upgrade some other package from experimental (namely nvidia drivers version 396 and cuda to build ffmpeg with cuda support). Everything is fine and I was happy until today, now I see that `apt upgrade` want to downgrade the driver packages to version 390.

I know about setting packages on `hold` but that won't upgrade anymore, I'll have to check manually for new packages version in the unstable branch. I know a bit about *apt pinning*, but looks to me like giving priority to some repository over others (I don't want any package from experimental to be installed automatically).

Is there a configuration where I can keep the experimental packages until the one in unstable reach the same or greater version?

**update**

list of the experimental packages installed

`aptitude search ~S~i~Aexperimental`:

```
i   fonts-anonymous-pro                                                - fixed width font designed for coders                                        
i A libaccinj64-9.2                                                    - NVIDIA ACCINJ Library (64-bit)                                              
i A libcublas9.2                                                       - NVIDIA cuBLAS Library                                                       
i A libcuda1                                                           - NVIDIA CUDA Driver Library                                                  
i A libcudart9.2                                                       - NVIDIA CUDA Runtime Library                                                 
i A libcufft9.2                                                        - NVIDIA cuFFT Library                                                        
i A libcufftw9.2                                                       - NVIDIA cuFFTW Library                                                       
i A libcuinj64-9.2                                                     - NVIDIA CUINJ Library (64-bit)                                               
i A libcurand9.2                                                       - NVIDIA cuRAND Library                                                       
i A libcusolver9.2                                                     - NVIDIA cuSOLVER Library                                                     
i A libcusparse9.2                                                     - NVIDIA cuSPARSE Library                                                     
i A libegl-nvidia0                                                     - NVIDIA binary EGL library                                                   
i A libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx                                            - NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)                            
i A libgles-nvidia1                                                    - NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 1.x library                                         
i A libgles-nvidia2                                                    - NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library                                         
i A libglx-nvidia0                                                     - NVIDIA binary GLX library                                                   
i A libnppc9.2                                                         - NVIDIA Performance Primitives core runtime library                          
i A libnppial9.2                                                       - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Arithmetic and Logic            
i A libnppicc9.2                                                       - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Color Conversion                
i A libnppicom9.2                                                      - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Compression                     
i A libnppidei9.2                                                      - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Data Exchange and Initialization
i A libnppif9.2                                                        - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Filters                         
i A libnppig9.2                                                        - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Geometry transforms             
i A libnppim9.2                                                        - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Morphological operations        
i A libnppist9.2                                                       - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Statistics                      
i A libnppisu9.2                                                       - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Support                         
i A libnppitc9.2                                                       - NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Threshold and Compare           
i A libnpps9.2                                                         - NVIDIA Performance Primitives for signal processing runtime library         
i A libnvblas9.2                                                       - NVBLAS runtime library                                                      
i A libnvcuvid1                                                        - NVIDIA CUDA Video Decoder runtime library                                   
i A libnvgraph9.2                                                      - NVIDIA Graph Analytics library (nvGRAPH)                                    
i A libnvidia-cfg1                                                     - NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library                              
i A libnvidia-compiler                                                 - NVIDIA runtime compiler library                                             
i A libnvidia-egl-wayland1                                             - NVIDIA binary Wayland EGL external platform library                         
i A libnvidia-eglcore                                                  - NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries                                            
i   libnvidia-encode1                                                  - NVENC Video Encoding runtime library                                        
i A libnvidia-fatbinaryloader                                          - NVIDIA FAT binary loader                                                    
i A libnvidia-glcore                                                   - NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries                                     
i A libnvidia-ml1                                                      - NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) runtime library                            
i A libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1                                          - NVIDIA PTX JIT Compiler                                                     
i A libnvrtc9.2                                                        - CUDA Runtime Compilation (NVIDIA NVRTC Library)                             
i A libnvtoolsext1                                                     - NVIDIA Tools Extension Library                                              
i A libnvvm3                                                           - NVIDIA NVVM Library                                                         
i A nvidia-alternative                                                 - allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider                              
i   nvidia-cuda-dev                                                    - NVIDIA CUDA development files                                               
i   nvidia-cuda-toolkit                                                - NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit                                             
i A nvidia-driver                                                      - NVIDIA metapackage                                                          
i A nvidia-driver-bin                                                  - NVIDIA driver support binaries                                              
i A nvidia-driver-libs                                                 - NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)                          
i A nvidia-egl-icd                                                     - NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)                                  
i A nvidia-egl-wayland-icd                                             - NVIDIA Wayland EGL external platform library (ICD)                          
i   nvidia-kernel-dkms                                                 - NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source                                     
i A nvidia-kernel-support                                              - NVIDIA binary kernel module support files                                   
i   nvidia-opencl-icd                                                  - NVIDIA OpenCL installable client driver (ICD)                               
i A nvidia-profiler                                                    - NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL                                         
i A nvidia-smi                                                         - NVIDIA System Management Interface                                          
i A nvidia-vdpau-driver                                                - Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix - NVIDIA driver                  
i A nvidia-visual-profiler                                             - NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL                                  
i A xserver-xorg-video-nvidia                                          - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

list of the experimental packages installed with version

`dpkg -l $(aptitude search ~S~i~Aexperimental |sed 's/^...//'|awk '{print $1}')`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version       Architecture Description
+++-===============================-=============-============-============================================================================
ii  fonts-anonymous-pro             1.002+clean-2 all          fixed width font designed for coders
ii  libaccinj64-9.2:amd64           9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA ACCINJ Library (64-bit)
ii  libcublas9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuBLAS Library
ii  libcuda1:amd64                  396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Driver Library
ii  libcudart9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Runtime Library
ii  libcufft9.2:amd64               9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuFFT Library
ii  libcufftw9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuFFTW Library
ii  libcuinj64-9.2:amd64            9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA CUINJ Library (64-bit)
ii  libcurand9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuRAND Library
ii  libcusolver9.2:amd64            9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuSOLVER Library
ii  libcusparse9.2:amd64            9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA cuSPARSE Library
ii  libegl-nvidia0:amd64            396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL library
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:amd64   396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)
ii  libgles-nvidia1:amd64           396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 1.x library
ii  libgles-nvidia2:amd64           396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library
ii  libglx-nvidia0:amd64            396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary GLX library
ii  libnppc9.2:amd64                9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives core runtime library
ii  libnppial9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Arithmetic and Logic
ii  libnppicc9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Color Conversion
ii  libnppicom9.2:amd64             9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Compression
ii  libnppidei9.2:amd64             9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Data Exchange and Initialization
ii  libnppif9.2:amd64               9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Filters
ii  libnppig9.2:amd64               9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Geometry transforms
ii  libnppim9.2:amd64               9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Morphological operations
ii  libnppist9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Statistics
ii  libnppisu9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Support
ii  libnppitc9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives lib for Image Threshold and Compare
ii  libnpps9.2:amd64                9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Performance Primitives for signal processing runtime library
ii  libnvblas9.2:amd64              9.2.148-1     amd64        NVBLAS runtime library
ii  libnvcuvid1:amd64               396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Video Decoder runtime library
ii  libnvgraph9.2:amd64             9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Graph Analytics library (nvGRAPH)
ii  libnvidia-cfg1:amd64            396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-compiler:amd64        396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA runtime compiler library
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64    396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary Wayland EGL external platform library
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:amd64         396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode1:amd64         396.54-2      amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fatbinaryloader:amd64 396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA FAT binary loader
ii  libnvidia-glcore:amd64          396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries
ii  libnvidia-ml1:amd64             396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1:amd64 396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA PTX JIT Compiler
ii  libnvrtc9.2:amd64               9.2.148-1     amd64        CUDA Runtime Compilation (NVIDIA NVRTC Library)
ii  libnvtoolsext1:amd64            9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Tools Extension Library
ii  libnvvm3:amd64                  9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA NVVM Library
ii  nvidia-alternative              396.54-2      amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                 9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit             9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
ii  nvidia-driver                   396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-driver-bin               396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:amd64        396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:amd64            396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-egl-wayland-icd:amd64    396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA Wayland EGL external platform library (ICD)
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms              396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-kernel-support           396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd:amd64         396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-profiler                 9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-smi                      396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA System Management Interface
ii  nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64       396.54-2      amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix - NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-visual-profiler          9.2.148-1     amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia       396.54-2      amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

upgrade output (I tried `apt-get` also and for some reason is different, longer, want to upgrade the boost libraries too)

`apt -s upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdns-export1102 libisc-export169
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdns-export1104 libisc-export1100
The following packages have been kept back:
  icu-devtools libboost-atomic1.62-dev libboost-atomic1.62.0 libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.62-dev libboost-chrono1.62.0
  libboost-context1.62-dev libboost-context1.62.0 libboost-coroutine1.62-dev libboost-coroutine1.62.0 libboost-date-time1.62-dev
  libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-dev libboost-exception1.62-dev libboost-fiber1.62-dev libboost-fiber1.62.0 libboost-filesystem-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.62-dev libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-graph-parallel1.62-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.62.0 libboost-locale-dev
  libboost-locale1.62-dev libboost-locale1.62.0 libboost-math1.62-dev libboost-math1.62.0 libboost-mpi1.62-dev libboost-mpi1.62.0
  libboost-program-options1.62-dev libboost-program-options1.62.0 libboost-python1.62-dev libboost-python1.62.0 libboost-random1.62-dev
  libboost-random1.62.0 libboost-regex1.62-dev libboost-regex1.62.0 libboost-serialization1.62-dev libboost-serialization1.62.0
  libboost-signals1.62-dev libboost-signals1.62.0 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.62-dev libboost-system1.62.0 libboost-test1.62-dev
  libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.62-dev libboost-thread1.62.0 libboost-timer1.62-dev libboost-timer1.62.0
  libboost-type-erasure1.62-dev libboost-type-erasure1.62.0 libboost-wave1.62-dev libboost-wave1.62.0 libboost1.62-dev libicu-dev libicu63
  libicu63:i386 liblxc1 libsane-common lldb lxc python-qscintilla2 python3-lxc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  btrfs-progs check fonts-wine gir1.2-gtk-3.0 git git-gui git-man gitk gtk-update-icon-cache isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common itstool libarmadillo9
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-3-dev libqbscore1.12 libqbsqtprofilesetup1.12 libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-tcl
  libwine:i386 nvidia-cuda-mps nvidia-egl-common nvidia-kernel-source nvidia-legacy-check nvidia-opencl-common opencl-clhpp-headers python-six
  python3-six qbs-common sqlite3 wine wine32:i386
35 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Inst nvidia-legacy-check [390.87-3] (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libisc-export1100 (1:9.11.5+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libdns-export1104 (1:9.11.5+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst isc-dhcp-client [4.3.5-4+b1] (4.4.1-2 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst isc-dhcp-common [4.3.5-4+b1] (4.4.1-2 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst btrfs-progs [4.17-1+b1] (4.19.1-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst check [0.10.0-3+b3] (0.12.0-0.1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst fonts-wine [3.0.4-1] (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst libgtk-3-common [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst libgtk-3-dev [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst libgtk-3-0 [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst gir1.2-gtk-3.0 [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst git-gui [1:2.20.0~rc2-1] (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all]) []
Inst gitk [1:2.20.0~rc2-1] (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all]) []
Inst git [1:2.20.0~rc2-1] (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst git-man [1:2.20.0~rc2-1] (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst gtk-update-icon-cache [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst itstool [2.0.5-1] (2.0.5-2 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst libarmadillo9 [1:9.100.6+dfsg-1] (1:9.200.6+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libgtk-3-bin [3.24.1-2] (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libqbscore1.12 [1.12.1+dfsg-2] (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst qbs-common [1.12.1+dfsg-2] (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst libqbsqtprofilesetup1.12 [1.12.1+dfsg-2] (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libsqlite3-dev [3.26.0-2] (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst sqlite3 [3.26.0-2] (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64]) []
Inst libsqlite3-0 [3.26.0-2] (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst libsqlite3-tcl [3.26.0-2] (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst wine [3.0.4-1] (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [all]) []
Inst wine32:i386 [3.0.4-1] (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [i386]) []
Inst libwine:i386 [3.0.4-1] (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [i386])
Inst nvidia-cuda-mps [390.87-3] (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst nvidia-egl-common [390.87-3] (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst nvidia-kernel-source [390.87-3] (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst nvidia-opencl-common [390.87-3] (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Inst opencl-clhpp-headers [2.0.10+git12-g5dd8bb9-1] (2.0.10+git23-gf0b7045-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst python-six [1.11.0-2] (1.12.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Inst python3-six [1.11.0-2] (1.12.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf nvidia-legacy-check (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libisc-export1100 (1:9.11.5+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libdns-export1104 (1:9.11.5+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf isc-dhcp-client (4.4.1-2 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf isc-dhcp-common (4.4.1-2 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf btrfs-progs (4.19.1-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf check (0.12.0-0.1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf fonts-wine (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf libgtk-3-common (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf libgtk-3-dev (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libgtk-3-0 (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf git-gui (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf gitk (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf git (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf git-man (1:2.20.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf gtk-update-icon-cache (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf itstool (2.0.5-2 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf libarmadillo9 (1:9.200.6+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libgtk-3-bin (3.24.1-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libqbscore1.12 (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf qbs-common (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf libqbsqtprofilesetup1.12 (1.12.2+dfsg-1 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libsqlite3-dev (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf sqlite3 (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libsqlite3-0 (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf libsqlite3-tcl (3.26.0-3 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf wine (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf wine32:i386 (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [i386])
Conf libwine:i386 (4.0~rc1-1 Debian:unstable [i386])
Conf nvidia-cuda-mps (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf nvidia-egl-common (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf nvidia-kernel-source (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf nvidia-opencl-common (390.87-4 Debian:unstable [amd64])
Conf opencl-clhpp-headers (2.0.10+git23-gf0b7045-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf python-six (1.12.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
Conf python3-six (1.12.0-1 Debian:unstable [all])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `apt` setup provides the behaviour you’re after: packages can be installed from experimental if requested explicitly, and once installed, they are implicitly held — they won’t be upgraded automatically (even if a newer version is uploaded to experimental) until unstable catches up. They won’t be downgraded either.

The NVIDIA packages which `apt` wants to touch in your case are `nvidia-cuda-mps`, `nvidia-egl-common`, `nvidia-kernel-source`, and `nvidia-opencl-common`, none of which you have installed from experimental (they don’t show up in your list of packages installed from experimental). Since they’ve been updated in unstable recently, `apt` wants to upgrade them; it’s not a downgrade from experimental.

`apt` isn’t doing anything wrong here, but you should install the affected packages manually from experimental to ensure everything is consistent.

Comment: Damn, I'm going blind, I'll look into it, thanks!